# Python -> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, munin

I am working on a Raspberry Pi 3 and I am trying to visualize some values of sensors on Munin. I am using Python in order to execute scripts on Munin.
I found a script to test and I am trying to execute it but I got the following error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "cpu_field", line 23, in
>  munin.main()
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
> 'main'

This is the script : https://github.com/CooledCoffee/python-munin/
Of course, I added at the beginning :

> ## !/usr/bin/env python

But, what I didn't understand is that others scripts are working like this one :
https://gist.github.com/tomoconnor/813813

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if you could put the code in the question as well.

Anyways. The python-munin you use is entirely different and provides no *main()* function (as it called in line 23). Names for python modules are not protected and
'munin' is a obvious choice used by more than one developer.
The first script should run with the module you get with

```
pip install python-munin
```

The other script uses [this python-munin module](https://github.com/samuel/python-munin) and you probably get it directly from the git repository. They are not compatible.

Comment: there is no code nor right/false. you must decide which module you want to use and write/use matching code to it. You can't mix it like you did.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the code I am using :

```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> 
> import munin
> 
> category = 'system' fields = [
>     'load1',
>     'load5',
>     'load15', ] vlabel = 'load'
> 
> def values():
>     with open('/proc/loadavg') as f:
>         data = f.read()
>     load1, load5, load15 = [float(s) for s in data.split()[:3]]
>     return {
>         'load1': load1,
>         'load5': load5,
>         'load15': load15,
>     }
> 
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     munin.main()
```

This is the answer I got with sudo python xxx, I got the same answer with sudo munin-run xxx :

```
   pi@dex:/etc/munin/plugins $ sudo python first
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "first", line 24, in <module>
        munin.main()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'
```

I thin you are right because when I installed munin with

```
pip install python-munin
```

it worked. But, then I installed this [python-munin module](https://github.com/samuel/python-munin) and it didn't work anymore. I removed the folder python-munin but I still got the same error.
How can I remove properly the [previous folder](https://github.com/samuel/python-munin) ?